# how can a process be killed with all its childern

Tags: ruby, linux, process

I have a situation where one xterm runs another xterm which runs a process.
I would like to set some kind of watchdog and kill all those windows in case of a stuck process.

I'm using Ruby to do this. When the first xterm is opened I get it's PID, and later when a SIGTERM is sent to it, only the first xterm window dies, but not the second.

It can be easily reproduced in irb:

```
irb(main):002:0> cmd = "xterm -e xterm -e sleep 1000"
=> "xterm -e xterm -e sleep 1000"
irb(main):003:0> pid = Process.spawn(cmd)
=> 669
irb(main):004:0> Process.kill(15, 669)
=> 1
```

This leaves the second xterm window open. How can all the process chain be killed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using either `ps xf` or `pstree`, you can dynamically see running processes hierarchy.

I've used [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to track which was the behaviour of those programs. It turned that they are checking the contents of `/proc/$pid/stat` and `/proc/$pid/status`, which give them information of who the process's parent is.

Probably, you will have to look for the processes whose Parent PID is equal to the PID you got (or that process's PPID).